# Cast UserPrincipal to WindowsIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, impersonation, azman

I've created a WCF service to authorize my apps through AzMan services. I've been trying to cast an UserPrincipal to WindowsIdentity by many ways. 
My scenario is:

A Web MVC calling a WCF service which needs to pass a windows identity variable to an AzMan class.

```
var u1 = new WindowsIdentity("MyDomain\\userName")
```

throws

> The name provided is not a properly formed account name.

```
var u2 = new WindowsIndetity("userName@MyDomain.com")
```

throws

> The user name or password is incorrect.

I'm able to get an UserPrincipal from "userName@MyDomain.com" calling

```
var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, upn);
```

In a nutshell I'm stucked because the company where I work uses AzMan everywhere.